# Mesh data structure used in popular 3D software

Tags: 3d, mesh, 3d-modelling

Anyone knows what kind of mesh representation data structures (half-edge, quad-edge, winged-edge etc) popular software like Lightwave 3D, Maya, Softimage, 3D studio and others use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indexed mesh is, by far, the most popular and used by at least Maya, LW, 3DS Max, and Modo. I'm not sure about XSI and Cinema 4D (haven't looked into their SDKs quite as much).

Wings3D uses winged edges, as its name implies, as did Mirai and Nendo from which it was based. These are some of the exceptional cases, but you can see as a result that they only support manifold meshes.

One of the reasons the basic indexed mesh structure is so popular over more fancy variants like the half-edge or winged-edge rep is because the indexed mesh maps very directly to the GPU. These packages are often focused on visualizing changes in realtime, such as character deformations on a frame-by-frame basis or sometimes even topology changes. Having a data structure that maps more directly to GPU often means less time spent synchronizing your application-specific data structures with what's on the GPU, so it tends to be the most efficient if your focus is on realtime GPU visualization/interaction in a viewport.

Another reason is because these packages handle such a wide range of mesh cases, including some challenging data like 6-manifold edges, a single polygon with multiple holes, etc. An indexed mesh supports all of these cases.

Sometimes a certain feature like a modeling tool that does a hefty amount of processing (ex: a decimator) might temporarily convert the indexed mesh to a different data structure like a half-edged rep for the sake of that one algorithm, converting back to the indexed mesh when it is done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It really help me. It seems like you have some experience on this subject

Comment: I did a lot of research into the SDKs of these packages before while wondering the same question about what sort of design I should settle on as the main storage. Technically structures like winged edges and half-edges are superior for a lot of algorithmic work involving traversal, edge flipping, collapsing, finding edge loops, etc., but often you come back to the lowest common denominator which just wants to focus on rendering the mesh to a viewport efficiently on a frame-by-frame basis. So it's generally handy to stick to the indexed mesh as that common denominator...

Comment: ... and convert to other reps temporarily when your operation is complex enough to warrant it.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this info. I'm currently building a 3D modeling application and everything worked fine and fast for simple operations. When I converted my mesh structure to a Quad-Edge for doing more complex mesh stuff, things got very very slow for large meshes so I was trying to figure out how the popular software do it. I think I should also take a look at the SDK's provided by these packages as you noted..